# i have this problem with null safety and The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have a collection trips that have departure , destination and vehicleID that it got from the table vehicle that has one to many association with trips that have name and type and driver how to display all the trips with the name of the vehicle with flutter and fire base using MVC architecture[image]

even if i used ? or ! .. i even used toString its thhe same problem

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Try using custom object https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#before_you_begin

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because Dart doesn't know the type of `data()`. Assuming that `tripDoc.data()` represents JSON data, try reading the variable once at the beginning and casting it to a `Map<String, dynamic>` before accessing the variables. That is how Dart represents JSON objects, you can learn more about it [in the `dart:convert` documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more)

```
final Map<String, dynamic> data = tripDoc.data();
String vehicleID = data['vehicleID'];
...
```